# How to fetch records from complex database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to fetch multiple records and single records at a time with multiple tables from MSSQL. Tables from where I need to collect data is like below :

```
1. tblExpenseType :
--> ExpenseTypeId | ExpenseTypeName
-->      1        | OVERTIME EXP.
-->      2        | REPAIRING EXP.
-->      3        | LU EXP.

2. tblMemoDetails :
--> MemoID | MemoNumber | FkTruckId
--> 1011   | 1          | 5
--> 1012   | 2          | 6
--> 1013   | 3          | 5
--> 1014   | 4          | 7

3. tblMemoExpense :
--> FkMemoNumber | FkExpenseTypeId | Amount
--> 1            | 1               | 150
--> 1            | 3               | 225
--> 2            | 1               | 50
--> 2            | 2               | 100
--> 2            | 3               | 150

4. tblMemoTrips :
--> FkTripId | FkMemoNumber | TripAmount
--> 11       | 1            | 1000
--> 9        | 2            | 500
--> 3        | 2            | 100
--> 4        | 2            | 2000
```

I'm trying to fetch data using below logic but it's making me confusing:

```
with MemoList
As
(select
    _jpMemo.MemoId as memoId
from TMS_JPMemo _jpMemo
where _jpMemo.FkTruckId = 5)

select 
    ML.memoId
    --,ME.FkExpenseTypeId 
    ,ME.Amount 
    ,ET.ExpenseTypeName
from TMS_MemoExpense ME
join MemoList ML on ML.memoId = ME.FkMemoId
join TMS_ExpenseTypes ET on ET.ExpenseTypeId = ME.FkExpenseTypeId
```

I need result like if I select FkTruckId 5 then it will show me below result.
I need results like below for FkTruckId 5 :

```
MemoNumber | TripDetails | TripAmount | OVERTIME | REPAIRING | LU
   1       |    11       |     1000   |   150    |    --     | 225
           |    Total    |     1000   |   150    |    --     | 225
```

And If I select FkTruckId 6 then it would show me a result like :

```
MemoNumber | TripDetails | TripAmount | OVERTIME | REPAIRING | LU
   2       |    9        |     500    |   --    |    --     | --
           |    3        |     100    |   --    |    --     | --
           |    4        |     2000   |   50    |    100    | 150
           |    Total    |     2600   |   50    |    100    | 150
```

So it's making me confusing how to solve this and how to achieve this type of complex data from tables.

Comment: I fail to see what relates expenses to trip #4 in particular in your second example. Why not (also) trip #3 and/or trip #9? What am I missing?

Comment: it can be display at #9 and #3 but last record is #4. So Expenses would be display to there.

Comment: Personally I would use your presentation layer to do a totals row; not SQL Server.

Comment: Then I wouldn't show the expenses with any of the trips, but merely with the memo's totals. And you only want to show memos that have both expenses and trips (which is why you don't show memo #3 for truck #5)? And if there were two memos for one truck to show, you'd show one total per memo, yes? Would you add to these a final total summing up all memos?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, when we will select truck #5 then there we will see both memo 1 and 3 but here I write #1 just for sample, there #3 will also display but expenses are not available there so expenses will be not shown there.

Comment: Then you should edit your request to add that memo to the result. So far it looks like you are dismissing memos purposely from the results by some rule you forgot to tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are displaying two different things per memo:

1. the memo's trips with their trip amount
2. the memo's expenses

Apart from belonging to the same memo, the two are not related, i.e. there are no expenses per trip. So it's actually two different things you want to show. Make this two separate queries. You can glue them together with `UNION ALL`, as you obviously want them both in one query result. Something like:

```
with memo as
(
  select memoid
  from tblmemodetails
  where fktruckid = 5
)
select memonumber, tripid, tripamount, overtime, repairing, lu
from
(
  -- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- The memos' trips. They have a trip amount but no further expenses of their own.
  select
    fkmemonumber as memonumber,
    fktripid as tripid,
    tripamount,
    null as overtime,
    null as repairing,
    null as lu,
    1 sortkey
  from tblmemotrips
  where fkmemonumber in (select memonumber from memo)
  group by fkmemonumber, fktripid -- one row per memo and trip
  -- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  union all
  -- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- The memos' expenses. They are not reated to particular trips.
  select
    fkmemonumber as memonumber,
    null as tripid,
    null as tripamount,
    sum(case when fkexpensetypeid  = 1 then amount end) as overtime,
    sum(case when fkexpensetypeid  = 2 then amount end) as repairing,
    sum(case when fkexpensetypeid  = 3 then amount end) as lu,
    2 as sortkey
  from tblmemoexpense
  where fkmemonumber in (select memonumber from memo)
  group by fkmemonumber -- one row per memo
  -- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
) data
order by memonumber, sortkey;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a series of `JOIN`s to put the tables in relation, and then conditional aggregation to pivot the data. This implies that the number of columns to pivot is fixed (if more values are added to table `tblExpenseType`, the query would need to be adapted) :

```
SELECT
    md.MemoNumber,
    mt.FkTripId AS TripDetails,
    mt.TripAmount,
    MAX(CASE WHEN et.ExpenseTypeName = 'OVERTIME EXP.'   THEN me.amount END) AS OVERTIME,
    MAX(CASE WHEN et.ExpenseTypeName = 'REPARINING EXP.' THEN me.amount END) AS REPARING,
    MAX(CASE WHEN et.ExpenseTypeName = 'LU EXP.'         THEN me.amount END) AS LU
FROM
    tblMemoDetails AS md
    LEFT JOIN tblMemoExpense AS me ON me.FkMemoNumber  = md.MemoNumber
    LEFT JOIN tblMemoTrips   AS mt ON mt.FkMemoNumber  = md.MemoNumber
    LEFT JOIN tblExpenseType AS et ON et.ExpenseTypeId = me.FkExpenseTypeId
GROUP BY 
    md.MemoNumber,
    mt.FkTripId AS TripDetails,
    mt.TripAmount
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation is the way to go.  I think the query looks a little more like this:

```
SELECT md.TruckId, md.MemoNumber,
       COALESCE(mt.FkTripId, 'Total') AS TripDetails, mt.TripAmount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN et.ExpenseTypeName = 'OVERTIME EXP.' THEN me.amount ELSE 0 END) AS OVERTIME,
       SUM(CASE WHEN et.ExpenseTypeName = 'REPARINING EXP.' THEN me.amount ELSE 0 END) AS REPARING,
       SUM(CASE WHEN et.ExpenseTypeName = 'LU EXP.' THEN me.amount ELSE 0 END) AS LU
FROM tblMemoDetails md LEFT JOIN
     tblMemoExpense me
     ON me.FkMemoNumber = md.MemoNumber LEFT JOIN
     tblMemoTrips mt
     ON mt.FkMemoNumber = md.MemoNumber LEFT JOIN
     tblExpenseType et
     ON et.ExpenseTypeId = me.FkExpenseTypeId
WHERE md.TruckId = @TruckId
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (md.TruckId, md.MemoNumber, mt.FkTripId, mt.TripAmount), () );
```

The `GROUPING SETS` generates the total.